# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

The bind_param that is failing is this

> $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $this->template->forms->reg_username, $this->template->forms->reg_password, $this->template->forms->reg_email, "Test");

the prepared statement is

> $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, email, referr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

The whole Register function is

```
public function Register() {

    unset($this->template->forms->error);
    $this->template->forms->setData();

    if(isset($this->template->forms->submit)) {

        if(!isset($this->template->forms->reg_username)) {
            $this->template->forms->error = "You must enter an username";
        }

        if(!isset($this->template->forms->reg_password)) {
            $this->template->forms->error = "You must enter a password";
        }

        if(!isset($this->template->forms->reg_password_confirm)) {
            $this->template->forms->error = "You must confirm your password";
        }

        if(!isset($this->template->forms->reg_email)) {
            $this->template->forms->error = "You must enter an email address";
        }

        if($this->template->forms->reg_password != $this->template->forms->reg_password_confirm) {
            $this->template->forms->error = "Your passwords must match";
        } else if(strlen($this->template->forms->reg_password) <= 5) {
            $this->template->forms->error = "Your password must be 6 characters or more.";
        }

        if(!$this->template->forms->error) {
            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO 'users' (username, password, email, referr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $this->template->forms->reg_username, $this->template->forms->reg_password, $this->template->forms->reg_email, "Adam");
            $stmt->execute();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is being loaded through __construct

Example

function __construct($mysqli, $template) {
  
  $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
  $this->template = $template;
  
 }

and my global file contains

$user = new Users($mysqli, $template);

where the $mysqli object is created.

Comment: Please note similar questions at the right side of this page. According to site rules you are supposed to use search before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your MySQL query. If the prepared statement couldn't be created the [`prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues) method will returns `false`. From the documentation of the `prepare()` method:

> **Return Values**
>
> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

The error message will be stored in the [`error` field](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) of your MySQLi connection object. Always add an error handling when you try to send a query or create a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an error in your SQL which @Progman pointed out in his answer. I believe the mistake is you have 'users' when it is supposed to be `users` which could cause it to fail. Change your SQL to what I have below and let me know if it works.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email, referr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```